# JQuery finding IRR (Internal rate of return)

Tags: javascript

From what I understand this should be the formula for calculating IRR. I already have all the other variables, but I am not sure how to formulate it to find the IRR from the equation using jquery.

I found a code similar to it but I am unsure as the how to reserve engineer to find the IRR. All help is appreciated thank you.

**Code**

```
var IRRval = [];

IRRval.push(-financed);
for (i = 0; i < period; i++) {
    IRRval.push(rental);
}

var IRR = IRRCalc(IRRval, 0.001) * 0.01;

function IRRCalc(CArray, guest) {
    inc = 0.000001;
    do {
        guest += inc;
        NPV = 0;
        for (var j=0; j < CArray.length; j++) {
            NPV += CArray[j] / Math.pow((1 + guest), j);
        }
    } while (NPV > 0);
    return guest * 100;
}
```

**IRR Formula**
[image: IRR Formula]

Comment: This question should be tagged with [tag:javascript] instead of [tag:jquery]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/ghalimi/4591338

Comment: @AlonEitan I have been using JQuery instead of Javascript for the rest page is possible for me to us keep use JQuery for this or do I have to switch back to Javascript for it?